# Handling chained Promise in computed property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

If I have a then() function on a promise it never resolves properly via a computed property

So this is OK,

```
  taxRate: computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('tax-rate', { current: true });
  })
```

But this is not, (outputs `[object Object]` - the promise - in the htmlbars template)

```
  taxRateValue: computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findRecord('tax-rate', { current: true }).then((taxRate) => {
      return taxRate.get('taxRateValue');
    })
  })
```

So what is the correct way to handling this without using an observer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first works because Ember Data uses a [PromiseObject](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html) internally. The inner workings are a bit tricky, but the gist of it is that the object fires observers when its promise resolves. The second doesn't work because you're no longer returning an object that implements Ember's object system, you're just returning a promise. The template doesn't know what to do with a promise, that's all in the object logic. As for your question:

> So what is the correct way to handling this **without using an observer?**

I'm afraid that's going to be impossible. You're going to need to use some kind of observer *somewhere*, either directly or indirectly. I would suggest using one directly to make it obvious what is going on:

```
taxRateValue: null,

taxRateValuePromise: observes('someProperty?', function() {
    this.get('store').findRecord('tax-rate', { current: true }).then((taxRate) => {
        this.set('taxRateValue', taxRate.get('taxRateValue'));
    })
}),
```

You could also re-use the PromiseObject, but that would require you to use an object instead of a value:

```
taxRateValue: computed(function() {
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
        promise: this.get('store').findRecord('tax-rate', { current: true }).then((taxRate) => {
            return taxRate.get('taxRateValue');
        })
    });
})
```

Then in your template:

```
{{taxRateValue.content}}
```

Comment: I would go with `PromiseObject` alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Comunication with store should happen inside route where one can do

```
  setupController(controller, model) {
    var promise = this.get('store').findRecord('tax-rate', { current: true })
      .then(taxRate => taxRate.get('taxRateValue'))
      .then(taxRateValue => controller.set('taxRateValue', taxRateValue)); //pass actual value

    controller.set('taxRateValue', promise); //pass promise to template to display loader
  }
```